# Implementing Folder Explorer with webbrowser C# winform

Tags: c#, browser, directory, explorer

I' trying to use webbrowser to create a folder explorer and I have few problems that I could not find any answer on the web... so I’ll appreciate your answers:

1. Can someone please explain how can I create the Up button (going to parent folder)?
2. How can I the explorer bar (on the left) to favorites or search as in windows explorer?
3. How can I implement the undo functionality (undelete files and folders)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do intercept calls to a url and inject the data from your application. That way you can write HTML and display whatever functionality you want.

This [Code Project WebBrowser Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx) might be useful too. I wouldn't be surprised if it allows you to handle the button click events on the navigation bar.